# Prestashop: Disable contact form

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I would like to disable the contact form in my prestashop installation but there is no plugin to do so. Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends what you mean by disabling contact form but here are few possibilities.

1. Modifying core contact controller (not recommended since you will lose custom code when updating Prestashop)

Open file `controllers/front/ContactController.php` and add this code inside the `ContactControllerCode` class.

```php
public function init()
{
    Tools::redirect('pagenotfound'); // redirect contact page to 404 page
}
```

2. Overriding contact controller

Create a new file `ContactController.php` and place it in folder `overrides/controllers/front/` and add the following code

```php
class ContactController extends ContactControllerCore {
    public function init()
    {
        Tools::redirect('pagenotfound'); // redirect contact page to 404 page
    }
}
```

3. Create a small module

Create a new directory `contactpagedisabler` in folder `modules` and inside create a file `contactpagedisabler.php` and put this code in

```php
class ContactPageDisabler extends Module 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->name = 'contactpagedisabler';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0';
        $this->author = 'whatever';

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Contact page disabler');
        $this->description = $this->l('Disables contact page.');
    }

    public function install() 
    {
        return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('actionDispatcher');
    }

    // hook runs just after controller has been instantiated
    public function hookActionDispatcher($params) 
    {
        if ($params['controller_type'] === 1 && $params['controller_class'] === 'ContactController') {
            Tools::redirect('pagenotfound'); // redirect contact page to 404 page
        }
    }
}
```

And then install this module from backoffice.

2nd option is simplest and it doesn't interfere with core files.

3rd option is probably overkill for such a small thing however it doesn't require overriding and if you or store manager ever needs the contact page back he can just disable the module from backoffice. 
The module could also be expanded/modified with configuration page where you could for example get a list of all pages in store and let user decide which ones to enable/disable etc.

**Update April 2018**

Forget first two options and use third. Always use a module (if possible) when modifying your shop.

Comment: Thank you! Solution #3 was exactly what I was looking for. Although it looks like an overkill I think it's the most convenient solution for the shop owner and I will not get any troubles when updating.

Answer (score 5):

If You want to block just contact form but You want to display contact page You can put in override\controllers\front\ContactController.php:

```html
<?php
class ContactController extends ContactControllerCore
{
 public function postProcess()
 {
  if (Tools::isSubmit('submitMessage'))
   {die('Form disabled');}
  else 
   parent::postProcess();
  //return null;

 }
 
}
```

This will disable ability to send mails.

Then You can cut contact form from theme: /themes/YOUR-THEME/contact-form.tpl
to not display contact form at all

**After this You have to delete file /cache/class_index.php to refresh classes in prestashop.**

Comment: I just got spam to my PS 1.5.4.0 and i disabled only post controller with your code. Works. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Barto's solution can also be achieved without an override.

Create another module `contactformdisabler`

```php
class ContactFormDisabler extends Module 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->name = 'contactformdisabler';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0';
        $this->author = 'whatever';

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Contact form disabler');
        $this->description = $this->l('Disables contact form submission.');
    }

    public function install() 
    {
        return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('actionDispatcher');
    }

    public function hookActionDispatcher($params) 
    {
        if ($params['controller_type'] === 1 
            && $params['controller_class'] === 'ContactController'
            && Tools::isSubmit('submitMessage')) {
               die('Contact form submission disabled');
        }
    }
}
```